# Common searchview for all fragments of tab layout or bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

How to implement `search view` to search items of `recycler view` which will work for all `fragments` of tab-layout?
**e.g** consider a tab layout containing three tabs. each of them has a recycler view in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a shared `ViewModel` with a `MutableLiveData<String>`. The view with the search view posts its contents to the shared `ViewModel`.
The other fragments have access to the that `ViewModel` and `observe` the `MutableLiveData<String>`.